# Meaning of # in a SQL Transaction

Tags: t-sql

Hi I was checking some store procedures of a product installed on my company, you know to see how other people solve problems and learn.

Among this I found this but I do not know what is the meaning of the # in the sql sp in the line select distinct objecttype from #CascadeCollect, any comments please?

### This is the whole sp..

```
begin
    -- get all the unique otcs collected in the temp table.
    declare @EntityCode int
    -- check if the entity requires special casing.
    declare @DbCascadeMask int

    -- special casing for calendar delete
    exec p_DeleteCalendar 

    declare otccursor cursor for 
    select distinct objecttype from #CascadeCollect    <------ here is the # ....

    open otccursor
    fetch otccursor into @EntityCode

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        select @DbCascadeMask = DbCascadeMask
        from EntityView as Entity
        where Entity.ObjectTypeCode = @EntityCode

        if @DbCascadeMask <> 0
        begin
            exec p_BulkDeleteGeneric @EntityCode
        end

        fetch otccursor into @EntityCode
    end
    CLOSE otccursor
    DEALLOCATE otccursor


    -- Return the count of entity instances that are still not deleted (because they
    -- require platform bizlogic/special casing. 
    select count(*) as NotDeletedCount from #CascadeCollect where processed = 2
end
```

Thanks for any comments !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single `#` as a prefix indicates a locally scoped temporary object. In this case it is clearly a table but you can also have `#temp` procedures as well.

It is only visible to the batch in which it is created (and any child batches) and dropped automatically when the batch exits.

So if that is the **whole** stored procedure then it is obviously expected to be run from another procedure that actually creates the temp table.

You can also have global temporary objects prefixed with `##`.

Answer (score 3):

a table prefixed with # is a local temporary table, it will be dropped once it is out of scope

```
create table #test(id int)

insert #test values (1)

select * from #test
```

If you run this from another connection `select * from #test` the table is not available since it is local